# err_EMPTY_RESPONSE (node + express)

Tags: node.js, http, express

I'm trying to learn node.js by writing chat programs. I already got the main functionality, however when I tried to add my CSS file I made some changes to the netcode to try and include static files (line 11) and now the server doesn't send data to the client. Instead, I receive an empty response error. Here is my server code.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');    
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    //connect
    var address = socket.handshake.address;
    console.log('connection from ' + address);
    io.emit('connection from ' + address);
    var user = address;

    //bring up to speed
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/log.txt', 'utf8');
    io.emit('up2speed', contents);
    console.log('bringing ' + user + ' up to speed...');

    //change name
    socket.on('set_user', function(nick){
        console.log('changing ' + user + ' to ' + nick + '...')
        user = nick;
    })

    //message
    socket.on('send_mes', function(msg){
        console.log(user + ' : ' + msg);
        io.emit('send_mes', user + ' : ' + msg)
        fs.appendFileSync('log.txt', user + ' : ' + msg + '\n');    
    });
});
```

I've tried retracing my steps but that just put me where I started. A page with no CSS.